# Is "presumably" in this sentence an interruption or just an adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, interrupting-phrase

> ... bringing me to Britain to, presumably, be interrogated and executed.

Or

> ... bringing me to Britain to presumably be interrogated and executed.

The way I see it, *presumably* can either be interpreted as an interruption or just an adverb in this sentence. If the former, then it should have commas on both sides, as in the first example. If the latter, then no commas. However, both of these examples seem a bit off to me. Which example is correct? And if both are correct, which is most natural?

Comment: It probably seems a bit off because you have been affected, either directly or indirectly,  by the old prescription that "split infinitives" are grammatically incorrect. According to this rule (to which some people still adhere) the two words forming the infinitive of a verb ("to be" in this case) should not be separated. To adhere to this 'rule' you would have to re-write the sentence as, say, ".. bringing me to Britain to be, presumably, interrogated and executed..."

Comment: @BoldBen Finally! I have been wondering what this feeling about certain sentences has been about. I have often intuitively re-written sentences to not include a split infinitive, but I never knew that I was doing so in adherence to some convention. The sentence you provided reads better to me, so I think I'll just re-write it into that. Thank you.

Comment: As I said the objection to split infinitives is no longer, as I understand it, supported by academic linguists. I also believe that it came about in the first place because 19th century academics compared English which has infinitives consisting of two words with Latin and other languages which do not and decided that, as the other languages have infinitives which can't be split English infinitives should not be split either.

Comment: With or without commas, *presumably* is a [sentence adverb](https://theeditorsblog.net/2016/02/21/a-tale-of-adverbs-and-the-comma/).

Comment: It's a pragmatic marker (subclass modal, showing speaker's estimate of likelihood). Traditionally a 'sentence adverbial'. It is a parenthetical element, extra to the grammar of the matrix sentence. It may be set off using a comma at each end, brackets or dashes (perhaps too heavy duty here), or zero punctuation. Zero punctuation works well (smooth running text, and still clear), but 'pauses for consideration', to emphasise the aside, may be indicated by commas if desired.